# Does Lightroom 5 support a hierarchy (multiple levels) of sub-collections?

Tags: lightroom

If I create a "collection set" and then create a collection within that set, am I able to create a sub-collection within that collection?  Will Lightroom 5 allow me to have hierarchies of multiple levels within Collections?
Jimvenice

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear so however you can create collection sets within collection sets with collections in them.  For example I have an animals collection set with a subcollection set of Osprey and a second one for Deer and each of those have multiple collections in them.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous poster said you can nest collection sets. You haven't stated what precisely you are actually trying to achieve and if this is for purposes of organisation then you might be better off using tags which are much more flexible. Collections and collection sets are better used for manging "projects" in Lightroom and tags are better used for organising the photographs so they can be found later to include in projects.